# Using a Raw Queryset inside a Custom Model Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to use a raw queryset inside a custom model queryset.

The issues is that I need to use/declare the queryset based model, before the model class is declared.

Can I declare a substitute of the model, that will be interpreted at the execution time ?

So, the code is like this:

```
class EntityModelQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def search_by_item(self, id__list):

            qs = Entity.objects.raw(


.............

class Entity
```

What about a second model with prefetch_related

```
qs = Entity.objects.raw( .. queryset = .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('item',
                     queryset=EntityItem.objects.all().only(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `self.raw(...)` instead of `Entity.objects.raw()`

```
class EntityModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet): # use models.QuerySet
    def search_by_item(self, id__list):
        qs = self.raw(...)
        return qs

class Entity(models.Model):
     objects = EntityModelQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Comment: what about calling another related model, with prefetch_related, see update

Comment: maybe something like `self.model._meta.get_field('item').rel.related_model`. But I think you can just use that EntityItem, define it before QuerySet.

Comment: Actually what exactly that `.. queryset`  means? Can you provide the full example with proper formatting?